# Cross site forgery on AJAX service

Tags: ajax, security, xss

I'm a little confused as to how to prevent cross site forgeries. Still.  I know there is a wealth of information out there, but I'm confused.

In [Steven Anderson's post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) he describes a form like this:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('fm1').submit()">
    <form id="fm1" action="http://yoursite/UserProfile/SubmitUpdate" method="post">
        <input name="email" value="hacker@somewhere.evil" />
        <input name="hobby" value="Defacing websites" />
    </form>
</body>
```

On someone else's site.

The solution given is a "anti-forgery" token, generated by the server, that is POST-ed back to with any requests in a hidden form.  That's cool, but what is to stop the hacker just downloading the form page, extracting the token and POSTing it?

My application for this is:  On the sign-up for to my website I'd like a AJAX function that sends the currently entered Username to the server which should respond "True/False"  if it is available or not.  This happens onKey so the user can pick a username that has not been used already.  The Submit button will enable when all the conditions for "new user" are met.

Clearly this is an opportunity for a hacker to use the service to "test" lots of usernames to see if they available - I know it's not exactly internet-banking level sort of risk, but I'd still like to service only requests from my application, not a hacker.

Any ideas how about these queries?

UPDATE:

So in my scenario.  I generate a Token (say some hashed value of the client's IP address) and the service expects to receive this back if it is give the information about whether the username is available or not.

-- The problem remains, someone off domain simply calls the service e.g. `/generateToken`   This looks at the client's IP... could be a hacker who knows.

Returns

```
{ token: 4uru32br }
```

Which is then submitted to the /isUsernameAvailable?token=4uru32br&partialUsername=usernam

Where does that get me?

Comment: " but what is to stop the hacker just downloading the form page, extracting the token and POSTing it?" A hacker will be downling his own token instead of the victim's.

Comment: Also note a CSRF token is not throttling login attempts because this is an entirely different issues as request forgery.

Answer (score 0):

> what is to stop the hacker just downloading the form page, extracting the token and POSTing it?

The [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), that's what.

> I'd like a AJAX function that sends the currently entered Username to the server which should respond "True/False" if it is available or not.

That's a user-enumeration vulnerability right there.

> Any ideas how about these queries?

Here's your new process:

1. Use email addresses for usernames.
2. Use CAPTCHA to prevent automation on registration forms.

**Email username does not exist:**

Show "success" message. Send email to address with one-time link. Register user after returns to your site with that link.

**Email username does exist:**

Show "success" message. Send email to that address with message saying "someone is trying to create an account with this address but it already exists".

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) and [user enumeration](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323044003/https://averagesecurityguy.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/user-enumeration-is-a-big-deal/).

> The solution given is a "anti-forgery" token, generated by the server,
>   that is POST-ed back to with any requests in a hidden form. That's
>   cool, but what is to stop the hacker just downloading the form page,
>   extracting the token and POSTing it?

Say Bob is a normal user on your site.

Chuck is an evil attacker.

Bob goes on your site and submits the comments form (in your code example). If there is CSRF protection, a token is included in this form too:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="zxcvbnnmm1235152" />
```

Bob's session has token `zxcvbnnmm1235152` stored for him server-side.

Chuck also has a login to your site because he has registered.

However, when he goes to this page he gets this token instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="lklkljlk898977" />
```

If Chuck downloads the page, gets Bob somehow (e.g. sends him an email) to access this page on Chuck's server, because the `csrf_token` doesn't match Bob's, Chuck can't post the message as Bob.

Bob can continue just fine, because the token in the form matches the one associated with his session.

CSRF is about stopping Chuck from submitting stuff as Bob, using Bob's browsing session.

> My application for this is: On the sign-up for to my website I'd like
>   a AJAX function that sends the currently entered Username to the
>   server which should respond "True/False" if it is available or not.
>   This happens onKey so the user can pick a username that has not been
>   used already. The Submit button will enable when all the conditions
>   for "new user" are met.
>
> Clearly this is an opportunity for a hacker to use the service to
>   "test" lots of usernames to see if they available - I know it's not
>   exactly internet-banking level sort of risk, but I'd still like to
>   service only requests from my application, not a hacker.

Yes, this is your user enumeration vulnerability.

Have username as email, and follow [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/47748/8340) on how to make this secure.

Answer (score -1):

The anti-forgery token is not a random code. Nor a reused token for several requests.

Rather, the server couples the token with the callers ip-address or session, for example by encrypting the ip+salt with a server-key.

Thus, if the attacker tries to download the token from your site, it won't be usable by the real client

Comment: "The anti-forgery token is not a random code". WHy not?

Comment: Because if the server had to store all tokens together with the clients ip it would be a lot to store I guess. Especially if backing and reposting should be allowed. Cheaper to send an encrypted state to the client.

Comment: OK I get the token is a one use code.  I think there is no way to avoid "harvesting" the above scenario using keys - correct me if I'm wrong - I think the only way would be to throttle results, as suggested.

Comment: Looking at the details of asp.net antiforgerytoken implementation, they actually generate two tokens; one as a form token and one as a cookie that will only be submitted to the same domain. By setting the cookie as html-only javascript is effectively stopped from harvesting it too for extra security.